# Need to call SOAP API in soapUI with the details in PHP code

Tags: php, ssl, soapui

```
$opts = array("ssl" => array("verify_peer" => false, "verify_peer_name" => false, 'crypto_method' => 128));

$client = new SoapClient('../../util/UPCCProvisioning.wsdl', array('location' => 'https://172.27.20.228:8080/axis/services/ScfPccSoapServiceEndpointPort', 'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS, 'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts)));
 
$i = 0;
$out = $client->getSubscriberAllQuota(array('subscriber' => array('attribute' => array('key' => 'USRIDENTIFIER', 'value' => '94' . $_POST['msisdn']))));
```

I am new to SOAP calls. I need to call this API with the details mentioned in the above code.
I tried it as follows and get an error mentioning

"**Sun Feb 07 02:38:14 IST 2021:INFO:Error getting response for [ScfPccSoapServiceEndpointBinding.getSubscriberAllQuota:Request 1]; javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**".

Can someone please be kind enough to assists with this?

[image]